# Unix join: return unmatched column without losing column order

Tags: macos, unix, join

I'd like to join two files, which share a common identifier column that is already sorted, using a Unix command-line utility such as "`join`". I'd like to keep unmatched rows, and also maintain the integrity of the column order between matched and unmatched rows, even when the identifier column is not in the first row.

For example, consider two files, 1.txt and 2.txt:

#### 1.txt:

```
val1,val2,key
1a,1b,1
2a,2b,2
3a,3b,3
```

#### 2.txt

```
key,val3,val4
1,1c,3d
3,3c,3d
```

Then, my desired output is:

```
key,val1,val2,val3,val4
1,1a,1b,1c,3d
2,2a,2b
3,3a,3b,3c,3d
```

Something like `join -t, -1 3 1.txt 2.txt` does what I want when limited to matched rows:

```
key,val1,val2,val3,val4
1,1a,1b,1c,3d
3,3a,3b,3c,3d
```

but it fails with unmatched rows (at least on OSX): `join -a 1 -t, -1 3 1.txt 2.txt` distorts the column order (notice how row 2's key is in column 3, not column 1):

```
key,val1,val2,val3,val4
1,1a,1b,1c,3d
2a,2b,2
3,3a,3b,3c,3d
```

What's the easiest way to achieve the result I'm looking for, in a Unix-like environment?

Perhaps this is a bug in `join` (I can't see any reason why what I'm looking for wouldn't be the preferred behavior in all cases, but I certainly could be missing something). If that's the case, I'd be happy to help fix...

Comment: `man join` . There is an `-e` (error) option (I think, maybe it is `-x`?)  to specify 'Missing', or 'NULL', etc. Does that help? Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help-- that option is for empty values in a column. It does nothing in the case of unmatched rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the output columns to get the result you desire:

```
$ join -a 1 -t, -1 3 -o 0,1.1,1.2,2.2,2.3 1.txt 2.txt
key,val1,val2,val3,val4
1,1a,1b,1c,3d
2,2a,2b,,
3,3a,3b,3c,3d
$
```

`-o 0` is the join column; the others are `file.field` numbers.  Note that it includes empty fields for the missing values (the double `,,` at the end).  If that's a major problem, you can obviously delete trailing (repeated) commas, and a little less obviously delete all but one of repeated commas in the middle of an output line.  I'd feed the output through `sed` to do that.

Test on Mac OS X 10.11.4 with both the BSD (/`usr/bin/join`) and GNU (home built — it happens to be in `/opt/gnu/bin/join`) versions of `join`.

Answer (score 0):

First store all lines from `2.txt` in an array, and then process `1.txt`.
For every found line take the first 2 fields of `1.txt` and the other fields from `2.txt`.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { from2[$1]=$0; next;}
         {if ($3 in from2) print $1 "," $2 "," from2[$3]; else print $0} ' 2.txt 1.txt
```