# Unix joins - similar to left join in sql

Tags: unix

I have two different files and would like to display the results side by side but just need a few columns from these files.

File1

```
Ab,cd,10
Ef,gh,20
Uv,xy,25
```

File2

```
Ab,cd,5
Ef,gh,15
```

Desired output:-

```
Ab,cd,10,20
Ef,gh,20,15
Uv,xy,25
```

And is it possible th get another column in the output that gives me the difference between the last 2 columns. I am sorry i am new to unix and did not know how to begin with it.

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36391183/620097 for how to manage column output in join. Good luck.

Comment: I do not understand `Ab,cd,10,20`, do you mean `Ab,cd,10,5` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `join` command -- read `man join` on your system. I'm assuming your system uses GNU coreutils.

You want the `-a` option to always print lines from the first file:

```
$ join -t , -a 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1 file2
Ab,cd,10,5
Ef,gh,20,15
Uv,xy,25,
```

You can add `-e 0` if you want to see the last line as `Uv,xy,25,0`

And to add a new column, you can pipe the output into this awk program:

```
join ... | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$5 = $3 - $4; print}'
```